# Error during database initialization TypeORMError: Driver not Connected

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am trying to establish a database connection. When i run `npm run dev`, I get the error message:

**Connected to database
Error during database initialization TypeORMError: Driver not Connected
at PostgresDriver.obtainMasterConnection (/Users/projectserver/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.js:868:19)
at PostgresQueryRunner.connect (/Users/project/server/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:68:18)
at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/Users/project/server/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:174:47)
at DataSource.query (/Users/project/server/node_modules/typeorm/data-source/DataSource.js:346:42)
at /Users/project/server/dist/Database/connection.js:37:26**

**connection.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import {Members} from "./entities/Members";
import { Users } from "./entities/Users";

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  const connection = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DB_HOST || "localhost",
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT) || 5432,
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME || "postgres",
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || "postgres",
    database: process.env.DB_NAME || "usv,
    entities: [Users, Members],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    schema: "usv",
  });

  console.log("Connected to database");

  // Add comments to the tables
  await connection.query(`
  COMMENT ON TABLE usv.users IS 'users for the various project'
`);
  return connection;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import express, { Application } from "express";
import http from "http";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { connectToDatabase } from "./Database/connection";

const app: Application = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT;

//initialize database:
connectToDatabase()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database!");
    // start the server after the database is initialized
    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error during database initialization", err);
  });

app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: have you tried to test the database connection with some command line tool like **psql** ?